# how to disable virtual machine auto start in Fedora 32

Tags: fedora

I want to disable autostart on a VM in Virtual Machine Manager, but I could not find the option in the UI. So I am using this command to try to disable autostart in Fedora 32:

```
% virsh autostart centos8 --disable
error: failed to get domain 'centos8'
```

I tried to list all domain like this:

```
% virsh  
Welcome to virsh, the virtualization interactive terminal.

Type:  'help' for help with commands
       'quit' to quit

virsh # list
 Id   Name   State
--------------------

virsh #
```

I alos tried to list all like this:

```
% virsh list --all

 Id   Name   State
--------------------
```

This is the virtual machine manager UI:

[image]

what should I do disable the auto start of virtual machine?

Comment: what is `visual machine manager`? ... do you mean `display manager`?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/144460/267016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look under the **Boot Options** tab of a VM in Virtual Machine Manager. Autostart is a checkbox option.

BTW, are you running `virsh` as root or as a user with the right permissions to do virsh/libvirt related stuff? (On Debian, there's a `libvirt` group for this. I don't know how Fedora does it, but probably in a very similar manner).

`virsh list --all` would show all of your VM "domains" if you had the right permissions.  And `virsh autostart` and `virsh autostart --disable` would also work in that case.

Answer (score 0):

bumped into your question as I was facing same issue (Centos 7.9 or Centos 8, similar to Fedora).

For anyone needing a simple command here it is how to check ($VM_NAME is machine/domain name):

```
virsh dominfo $VM_NAME | grep -i autostart
```

will show

```
Autostart:      enable
```

You can disable with:

```
virsh autostart --disable $VM_NAME
```

and now the output will be:

```
Autostart:      disable
```